# Dynamically add in-app products (non consumable) in itunes for specific app

Tags: c#, asp.net, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We are using consumable type of product items, which are having same price tier. But apple rejected the same and apple suggested us to use non-consumable product type.

Now, we want to add non-consumable product dynamically when any item is added in to content management system. can we add product to itunes through our own system? Please help us to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Apple has not provided any such API till now to upload products manually. So, We have to add all the products from iTunes Connect manually. There is not other alternative. :)

Thanks

Comment: it's been 5 years since this answer. do we still have an api?

Comment: No I don't think it's still there