# iOS in app purchase API

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm building an App where clients can create digital magazines and publish them to iOS devices. The magazines can be paid, and should use in app purchases.

It is my understanding that in app purchase items are added manually to the iTunes connect. Because the creation of magazines is managed by the client, when the client adds a new edition of the magazine it should be available automatically to the iOS App.

How can I add new items to the iTunes connect without doing manually? Is there an API for this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675803/dynamically-add-in-app-products-non-consumable-in-itunes-for-specific-app

Comment: I can't get around the fact how the other Apps do this... Do they really have to manually insert a item in the itunes connect every time a user creates a new magazine?

Comment: the keyword here the _newsstand_. https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/

Comment: @JoelOliveira : Yes till now apple has not provided any API to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you holex, that's just about it. The Newsstand API (developer.apple.com/newsstand) actually solves the problem.

Thanks